# Was the pain box from Dune the inspiration for the pain box in Phantasm?

Tags: dune, phantasm-1979

In both *Dune* and *Phantasm*, a character must stick their hand into a box where they suffer searing agony which only releases them once they have accepted the pain and faced their fears.

Is there any evidence (interviews, behind the scenes, whatever) where Don Coscarelli (writer/director/producer of *Phantasm*) addresses this?

Alternately, perhaps both take their inspiration from an earlier work I am unfamiliar with.

Comment: @Valorum that’s just the sort of detail I hope to notice when I see the new remaster on Thursday. I’d call that proof if you want to add it as an answer.

Comment: https://www.horrornewsnetwork.net/ten-things-you-might-not-know-about-phantasm/ - See item #6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In terms of evidence, there isn't much to go on (nothing in the director's commentary, nothing in the making-of movie, etc) but there's a fairly big clue in that the event in Phantasm took place in **Dune's Cantina**.

[image: Ther]